# C Program to find Sum of First and Last Digits of 4 Digit Number

Tags: c

I have written the following code but it gets stuck:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    clrscr();
    unsigned int num;
    unsigned int rev=0;
    int rem,sum=0;
    printf("Enter a 4 digit number:\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    rem=num%10;
    sum=sum+rem;
    while(num!=0)
      { rem=num%10;
        rev=(rev*10)+rem;
        num/10;
      }
    rem=rev%10;
    sum=sum+rem;
    printf("Sum of first and last digits of number=%d",sum);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: I have realised that it is always better to check and debug to program using a debugging tool, such as the Turbo debugger. It helps avoid such trivial mistakes, an advice for beginners!

Comment: I recommend you first read  **[how to ask perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)** and then edit your question accordingly to attract more people to your question.

Comment: The line `num/10;` doesn't change `num`, so the loop never terminates.  You need `num /= 10;`.  It seems like a long-winded way to do it.  You should check that `scanf()` got a number, that the number is in the range 1000..9999 (otherwise it isn't a 4-digit number under the normal rules of English language), and then you could use `num / 1000 + num % 10` to get the sum you need.

Comment: Yes, something that would have been obvious from one printf() in the loop or if using Turbo Debugger :(

Comment: Thanks. Yes. There was an error in the num/10 statement. It should have been num/=10. I have not use decision control statements yet but ya, scanf() was getting the number. :)

Comment: and you have not done any debugging either. please do that the next time first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the Most significant digit divide it by 1000, it will return u Most significant digit, to get least significant digit take modulus by 10, e.g

```
int rem = num%10;
int sum = num/1000+ rem;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this one line, specific to 4 digits:

```
printf("The sum of first and last digit of %d is: %d",n,n/1000+n%10);
```

And the problem in your code is:

```
    while(num!=0)
      { rem=num%10;
        rev=(rev*10)+rem;
        num/10;///-------------------->this line do num/=10; instead
      }
```

Correct it this way:

```
    while(num!=0)
      { rem=num%10;
        rev=(rev*10)+rem;
        num/=10;
      }
```